# UK Urgent Visitor visa Processing Delayed

Tags: visas, uk

I and my husband applied for UK visitor visas. He applied for the urgent one and mine was regular. After 10 days of biometrics I received my passport with visa on it but my husband passport has not been arrived yet. It is Worth mentioning that we both received same emails from UKVI. Emails were stating 
“your visa application is issued”. We have also asked from Gerry’s person about this delay. He told us that passport is in the British Embassy in Islamabad.
Did anyone else face this situation in the past?
Our 212GBP are just wasted. It was much better we would have applied for regular one

Comment: It's worth noting that the priority option is never guaranteed - most likely, the same thing would have happened with the standard option and it's specific to your husbands application.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry but there is nothing anyone can do here to help you with that. It's life, stuff happens and this is not the right forum to advise why specifically this has happened to you  and what's the remedy. There are many factors that can affect quick turnaround of an application, even with priority processing.

The only solution is to wait for his passport. You could try contacting them via the paid helpline but that doesn't tell you much.